# Entity Framework avoid inserting doubles

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is possible using Entity Framework (5).
To be simple, I have 2 classes

```
public class Value
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int Content {get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Constraint> Constraints {get; set;}
}

public class Constraint
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Type {get; set;}
}
```

In my business logic I consider two similar Constraint if the couple (Name, Type) is similar.
Somewhere in the code I associate Constraint to Value like:

```
Value v1 = new Value() { Content = 42 };
Constraint c1 = new Constraint() {Name = "A", Type = "B" };
v1.Constraints.Add(c1);

Value v2 = new Value() { Content = 43 };
Constraint c2 = new Constraint() {Name = "A", Type = "B" };
v2.Constraints.Add(c2);
```

and then, I have another part of the persistance layer that is reponsible for inserting the values in the database:

```
ValueRepository.Insert(v1);
ValueRepository.Insert(v2);
```

Having unique constraint on the "Constraint" table on the couple (Name, Type), I want to avoid having insertion error when inserting c2. **How do I tell to EF to consider c2 the same as c1?**

PS: I can not use Constraint repository to instanciate Constraint entities.

Comment: Give the value of Id while inserting the data into database.

Comment: What other properties does Constraint have that would lead to the existence of more than one object with the same key value? What do you intend on doing when there are two Constraints with identical keys - notify the user and ask them to change the input, or throw a different exception instead of the Unique Key Violation? Or do you want to remove all of the dupes except one?

Comment: I don't want to keep duplicates of the same Constraint in the database table that's what I'm trying to do. adding to that, after insertion I want c1 to point v1 and v2 values and not only v1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF cannot do this for you because it is built on the assumption that entities are not exchangeable values. Entity instances map to rows. Each different instance is independent.

Therefore you need to ensure that you don't double-insert. Techniques for that in order of preference:

1. Change the logic of your app to not generate duplicates
2. Before creating an entity instance, test the database whether it already exists (IOW run a query)
3. Handle the exception.

Do not use (3) because it is hard to handle *just* this error. Most likely you will also swallow unrelated ones. For example you might mistake a network error as an indication that the entity already existed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking to add table insert trigger to avoid inserting doubles but I don't know what would be the state of the c2 entity.

Comment: Don't change the data behind the back of EF. It will start acting weird because it thinks c2 is in the DB while it really isn't.